# Can Big Sur disable external drives?

Tags: disk-utility, usb, external-disk, big-sur

Been having several seemingly unrelated problems with a new (2019) MacBook Pro (MBP).  All of them seem more like software than hardware (as a retired software engineer with ten years as an electronics tech prior, I should be able to judge).

Four or five days ago, all four external disks dismounted and will not remount.  Disk Utility and `diskutil` and the system info app says there are no disks connected.

Since this is one of those USB-C only Macs, I had a multiport adapter hub connected to two of the ports, and the USB-A for the disk drives plugged into that.  The cable goes to a seven-port separately powered hub which in turn went to the four drives.  Three of them were powered by the hub, and according to the lights, still get power.  The other has it's own power connection and does have a light on.  The room was unoccupied with a door closed, so no one could have bumped any cables.

Thinking that the adapter hub may have failed, I shut down MacOS, unplugged one of the drives and plugged it into a second USB-A on the adapter.  Booted the MBP; still no drives.

Swapped the two cables of that drive and the seven-port hub on the two ports of the adapter hub.  Still nothing.  Unplugged the seven-port hub and plugged in a DVD drive that needs USB power.  It worked and tried to play a DVD.  So the adapter hub is presumed OK.

Disconnected all from the new MBP.  Got out a "retired" 2012 MBP with Catalina that had last year used all four drives with the same seven-port hub.  Plugged in the seven-port hub to that and powered it on.  After logging in, looked for external drives in Finder and in Disk Utility.  NONE!

So apparently, Big Sur did something to all four drives while I was out of the room that made all of them unrecognizable.  **Is there another explanation?  Is there any way to not lose those backups?**

UPDATE: I suspected the MBP and/or Big Sur, since so many other problems appeared when I got them.  But this one appears to be the seven-port hub.

Possibly related but not duplicates (some symptoms different):
[USB drives connected to hub disppearing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110430/usb-drives-connected-to-hub-disppearing)

Comment: Did you try with different cables? Did you try with a direct connection from the Mac to a drive (without the hub)?

Comment: What's the make(s) and model(s) of the hub(s)? If you are daisy-chaining USB hubs, that may be a problem.

Comment: I don't think daisy-chaining is the issue, since the configuration worked for a year on the old machine, and for three months on the new one.  But it does appear to be the second hub, though still puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably **No**.  I looked at the USB chain with System Info and found that both machines can see all the USB ports and hubs including the one that I forgot is built into the Seagate drive (which has two unused USB-A ports on it).

I then connected three of them to the adapter hub, and they mounted.

Removed the seven-port hub completely.  Plugged the large Seagate and the small older drive into the two-port adapter hub.  Then the two other drives into the hub built into the Seagate.  All mounted.

So, somehow, the seven-port hub (after more than a year with no problems) prevented any of the drives connected to it from being recognized as drives.

Puzzling how a hub can provide power and allow something downstream to be recognized as another hub, yet not allow it to be recognized as a disk.  Perhaps that merits a separate question.

Comment: If the hub is pretty old, perhaps the power supply has gone off spec and is not providing the correct voltage, wattage, amps, etc to power the drives. If the drives aren't spinning up (you don't say if they are spinning or not) that's a sign.

Comment: One drive had its light on.  And the Seagate has its own separate power.  No way to tell whether they are spinning.